# Migrating .NET/MySQL app. to DB2

Tags: .net, mysql, db2

I want to migrate my existing desktop Windows .NET 3.5 app. that uses MySQL as backend to DB2 Express C. I downloaded IBM Migration Toolkit to migrate the database. I have further queries:

1. How accurate is IBM Migration Toolkit? Are there any issues?
2. For the application, just changing the connection string will do or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding question #2:**  If you are using ODBC though ADO.NET then you should be able to just change the connection string, but if you are leveraging the connector.net mysql driver then you may need to update the service layer in your application to use either odbc or a db2 native driver for .net.

Enjoy!